# Identity 2.0 sms password reset with token

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

Every time I see this brought up people confuse it with two factor authentication which is laid out in the new Identity 2.0 template. But is there a process in place to generate a usable (not 100 characters long) reset token for a user and deliver it through sms? Before I start to build my own method, I was hoping to see at least some advice on how to generate a secure token that is smaller (possible using PhoneNumberTokenProvider I assume??), and hopefully not have to alter my tables further.

This seems like the first thing you'd want to be able to do once you have a user with a verified phone number.

Comment: for anyone still looking, i just answered the same question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/34308708/648484

Comment: Did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can plug in a different UserTokenProvider to swap out the tokens for confirmation/reset password.  You are free to use the built in PhoneNumberTokenProvider instead if you prefer generating a time based TOTP token.

The reason the default tokens are long, is that they are self signed tokens with their lifetime embedded in the token.

Comment: How would you use the token generated by another token provider for confirmation on the ResetPasswordAsync() method the other token? Do these tokens never time out?

Comment: The tokens contain its purpose (for confirmation or reset password), its expiration (1 day), and the user this token belongs to.

Comment: for anyone still looking, i just answered the same question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/34308708/648484